# Is there the uses of pointer right?

Tags: c

I want to use pointer in here, but it's not right.
It has Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 (1) in

```
(*(exy + i)) = g;
```

Please tell me how use the operation of pointer.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define M 3
#define N 3


int readmoduluskai(filename, time, gcoef, kcoef, ge, ke, dm)
char filename[];
char dm[];
double *time, *gcoef, *kcoef;
double *ge, *ke;
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    
    printf("Modulus file name : ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
        printf("\7\n Cannot open file..\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //fscanf(fp, "%12lg", &ge);
    //fscanf(fp, "%12lg", &ke);
    //printf("%12lg %12lg \n", ge, ke);
    
    while (3 == fscanf(fp, "%lg %lg %lg", time, gcoef, kcoef)) {
        printf("%12lg %12lg %12lg \n", *(time), *(gcoef), *(kcoef));
        time++;
        gcoef++;
        kcoef++;
        i++;
    }
    //printf("Please enter the constitutive parameters : ");
    //scanf("%s", dm);
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}

int readdata(file, t, ex, ey, ez, eyz, ezx, exy, ekk)
char *file;
double *t, *ex, *ey, *ez, *eyz, *ezx, *exy, *ekk;
{
    double a, b, c, g;
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;

    printf("File name : ");
    scanf("%s", file);
    
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(file, "r"))) {
        printf("Cannot open file..\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (4 == fscanf(fp, "%lg %lg %lg %lg", &a, &b, &c, &g)) {
        printf("%12lf %12lf %12lf %12lf \n", a, b, c, g);
        (*(t + i)) = a;
        (*(ex + i)) = b;
        (*(ey + i)) = c;
        (*(exy + i)) = g;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    char filename[20];
    char dm[2];
    char file[20];
    
    double *time;
    double ptime = 0;
    time = &ptime;
    double *gcoef;
    double pgcoef = 0;
    gcoef = &pgcoef;
    double *kcoef;
    double pkcoef = 0;
    kcoef = &pkcoef;
    double *ge;
    double pge = 0;
    ge = &pge;
    double *ke;
    double pke = 0;
    ke = &pke;
    double *t;
    double pt = 0;
    t = &pt;
    double *ex;
    double pex = 0;
    ex = &pex;
    double *ey;
    double pey = 0;
    ey = &pey;
    double *ez;
    double pez = 0;
    ez = &pez;
    double *eyz;
    double peyz = 0;
    eyz = &peyz;
    double *ezx;
    double pezx = 0;
    ezx = &pezx;
    double *exy;
    double pexy = 0;
    exy = &pexy;
    double *ekk;
    double pekk = 0;
    ekk = &pekk;
    
    
    time = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    gcoef = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    kcoef = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    ge = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    ke = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    
    
    readmoduluskai(filename, time, gcoef, kcoef, ge, ke, dm);//read the modulus parameters
    
    readdata(file, t, ex, ey, ez, eyz, ezx, exy, ekk);
    
    
    free(time);
    free(gcoef);
    free(kcoef);
    free(ge);
    free(ke);
    
    return 0;
}
```

how can I change it

Comment: Stop using K&R style function definitions. That has been obsolete for 30 years.

Comment: `double pexy` only provides space for 1 element. `(*(exy + i)) = g;` causes undefined behavior when `i > 0`.

Comment: You need to pass arrays to `readdata()`. You should also pass the length of the arrays, so that it doesn't try to write outside the arrays.

Comment: Although `(*(exy + i)) = g;` is syntactically correct and type-correct, few C programmers would fail to write `exy[i] = g;` instead.  The two mean exactly the same thing, and the latter is easier to read and understand.

Comment: This programming style is an absolute mess. I'm not sure where you learned to program this way, but I would strongly recommend to reconsider the teaching material or teacher. Generally speaking, if you have so many parameters to a function (9), and you have so many lines of variable declarations and assignments (over 40 in main) you should get a hint you're doing something wrong. You should probably be using structs here.

Comment: This is unnecessarily cumbersome: `double *ge; double pge = 0; ge = &pge;` If you switch lines you can get `double pge = 0; double *ge = &pge;` Which is 1/3 less lines. And for some of them the initialization is completely useless as you do `ge = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));` a bit later.

Comment: I do not understand your question "_how can I change it_". You are already using a pointer in the correct way by `(*(exy + i)) = g;`. However, as others point out, there is undefined behavior if `i` is not zero. What dou you want to achieve?